# Why does a user filter result in an "Unsupported query"?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the .NET Microsoft Graph API to issue a query against my Azure AD as follows:

```
var userRequest = _graphClient.Users.Delta();
var filter = "startswith(displayName,'K')";
var users = await userRequest.Request().Filter(filter).GetAsync();
```

According to Fiddler traffic, this results in a HTTP GET that looks like:

```
GET /v1.0/users/microsoft.graph.delta?$filter=startswith(displayName,'K')
```

Response:

```
400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported query.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "UUID",
      "date": "2017-12-04T16:26:23"
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried a filter like:

```
var filter = "accountEnabled eq true";
```

But the same 400 error occurs.

Removing the filter results in a successful query.

Why is this filter resulting in an "Unsupported query"? From what I read in the [Supported queries, filters, and paging options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) docs it sounds like these are valid queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `/users` endpoint supports the `$filter=startsWith()` query parameter, but the `/users/delta` endpoint does not. The `/delta` endpoint has a number of query limitations, including this one.

Comment: Where can I find the filter limitations of the `/delta` endpoint? As mentioned, I also just tried a simple `accountEnabled eq true` and that was rejected with the same error as well. Can I do any filtering with `/delta`?

Comment: To be honest, the documentation here is pretty thin. It really should be mentioned on the [Delta Overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview#optional-query-parameters) but it is only mentioned in terms of it `$filter` coming in the beta endpoint.

Comment: So is filtering not possible at all with `/delta` at the moment?